# Is 4-chlorotoluene also an IUPAC name for 1-chloro-4-methylbenzene?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, aromatic-compounds

I think that toluene is a common name for 1-methylbenzene. And in IUPAC nomenclature, we must provide formal prefixes and suffixes along with correct numbering so the only correct option must be 1-chloro-4 methylbenzene.

Comment: I should have searched before answering, but: Possible duplicate of [Is 3,5-diethyltoluene an accepted IUPAC name?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/33380)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The use of 'toluene' as a parent hydrocarbon in nomenclature is described in Rule **P-22.1.3** in [*Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry: IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013*](http://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/ebook/9780854041824#!divbookcontent).

> These names [toluene, xylene, and mesitylene] are retained due to a long and well established tradition. Toluene and xylene are preferred IUPAC names, but are **not freely substitutable**; toluene is substitutable under certain conditions, but **only for general nomenclature**. (emphasis mine)

*"General nomenclature"* refers to any name generated by the use of IUPAC principles, rules, and conventions, whereas the *"preferred IUPAC name"* (PIN) refers to a name that is preferred among two or more names generated from two or more IUPAC recommendations. The introduction **P-10** reads:

> Any name other than a preferred IUPAC name, as long as it is unambiguous and follows the principles of the IUPAC recommendations herein, is acceptable as a 'general IUPAC name", in the context of a 'general IUPAC nomenclature'.

---

As stated in **P-22.1.3**, in the construction of a PIN for the molecule below, the use of 'toluene' as the parent hydrocarbon is not permitted; the PIN is 1-chloro-4-methylbenzene.

[image: 1-chloro-4-methylbenzene]

Regarding the substitution of toluene in general nomenclature, **P-15.1.8.2.2** lists the characteristic groups that can be used in general nomenclature:

> [...] halides $\ce{-Br, -Cl, -F, -I}$, pseudohalides $\ce{-N3, -NCO}$ (and chalcogen analogues), $\ce{-NC}$, substituent groups derived from the halogen oxo acids $\ce{-ClO, -ClO2, -ClO3}$ (similarly for groups in which $\ce{Cl}$ is replaced by $\ce{Br}$ or $\ce{I}$), $\ce{-NO2}$ and $\ce{-NO}$, and $\ce{-OR}$ ($\ce{R}$ = alkyl groups), and chalcogen analogues, and $\ce{-SO-R}$ and $\ce{-SO2-R}$, and $\ce{Se}$ and $\ce{Te}$ analogues.

Since chloride falls under this list, the name 4-chlorotoluene is permissible in general nomenclature, but it is not the preferred IUPAC name.

---

Note that there is no space between the prefix 'chloro' and the parent hydride name 'toluene'.

Also note that there is no such thing as '1-toluene'; in the name '4-chlorotoluene', for example, the methyl group of toluene is automatically assigned the locant '1' (see figure below from the Recommendations). Therefore, the name '4-chloro-1-toluene' is incorrect.

[image: Locant numbering in toluene]

Comment: The question says "the  iupac name(s) of the compound is/are" so does it refer to pin or general name

Comment: Sorry but I can't interpret ambiguous wording for you.